# ConcurrentModificationException over list

Tags: java, concurrency

I'm trying to iterate over a list of objects. I get the ConcurrentModificationException error. However I am not changing/removing the objects. Also the method game.getRooms() is synchronized. What am I doing wrong?

```
Iterator<Room> it = game.getRooms().iterator();
     while (it.hasNext()) {
        Room room = it.next();
        synchronized (room) { 
           Image tile;
           if (room.getTile() == Tiles.WALL) {
              tile = TileGraphics.wall;
           } else if (room.getTile() == Tiles.EXIT) {
              tile = TileGraphics.exit;
           } else {
              tile = TileGraphics.floor;
           }
           tile.setAlpha(room.getLight());
           tile.draw(room.getX() * tile.getWidth(), room.getY() * tile.getHeight());
        }
     }
```

Stacktrace:

> java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
>       at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
>       at game.screens.GameScreen.render(GameScreen.java:62)
>       at org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame.render(StateBasedGame.java:199)
>       at org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer.updateAndRender(GameContainer.java:681)
>       at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.gameLoop(AppGameContainer.java:408)
>       at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:318)
>       at game.Main.main(Main.java:23)
>   Tue Jun 07 22:05:03 EEST 2011 ERROR:Game.render() failure - check the game code.
>   org.newdawn.slick.SlickException: Game.render() failure - check the game code.
>       at org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer.updateAndRender(GameContainer.java:684)
>       at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.gameLoop(AppGameContainer.java:408)
>       at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:318)
>       at game.Main.main(Main.java:23)

Line 62 is being `Room room = it.next();`

Comment: are multiple threads accessing this piece of code? And what is the stacktrace of the exception.

Comment: Does it happen, too, if you synchronize on "game" around the whole iteration starting before you get the iterator?

Comment: Which line is the CME thrown. And what is the stacktrace.

Comment: It also happens when I synchronize it on game.

Comment: Are the methods which modify or produces the rooms collection synchronized on game, too?

Comment: The only method that modifies the list is in the Game class itself and is synchronized on itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this list is being used in a multithreaded application, any thread could 
be accessing the list and modifying/iterating over the backing list with the iterator.

Is your list being created with a synchronised wrapper? (Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList()) for example).

Synchronising the declaration of the list is not enough, nor is just synchronizing the method call. Every place the list is iterated over needs a synchronized block, synchronized against the list.

Read http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)

Comment: The list is made by the server sent to the client. The client never modifies it, only re-declarates it often.

Comment: How exactly is the list sent to the client? And how does the client receive it?

Comment: I tried synchronizing every method where the list occurs on the list itself. It didn't help.

Comment: It is sent used ObjectOutputStream and received using ObjectInputStream

Comment: is the list created with a collections.synchronizeList on the server side? I'm guessing it's not.

Comment: The answer below is probably your best bet if you cannot change the server's implementation, even if it's a little cheaty. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270110/concurrentmodificationexception-over-list/6270551#6270551 I would actually copy the list in the getRooms method rather than here, this would preserve the list wherever it's accessed. The only downside is you cannot then modify the list without another access method.

Comment: The other solution is to check if the object being deserialized is a collection object and wrap it then during the deserialization process.

Comment: I added Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList()) when creating the list and it worked! Thank you Sir!

Answer (score 4):

There is certainly code that modifies that list somewhere else in another thread. So an option is to create a copy of the list and iterate it (with foreach) instead:

```
List<Room> copy = new ArrayList<Room>(game.getRooms());
for (Room room : copy) {..}
```

Comment: This got it working actually. I will however try to fix it rather than going around the problem.

Comment: @Rob Fox - that might be the best solution depending on the code that does the modification. But without seeing it I can't suggest a better one.

Comment: I got it working using Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList())

Comment: This may be less efficient depending on the scenario.

Comment: When would this approach be more efficient?

Comment: if you are often changing but rarely iterating, then a copy is fine. If you are rarely modifying but often iterating then a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is better. the sunchronizedList may mean unnecessary locking.

Comment: Whether copying or locking is more expensive depends on the amount of contention on the list relative to the size of the list.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that getRooms is synchronized doesn't affect the code at all.  It only affects the call to getRooms().

The best approach would be to try synchronized(game){ game.getRooms(); .. iterate }

Or even synchronized(game.getRooms()){ ... iterate }

Comment: Then synchronize on game.getRooms()

Answer (score 0):

Slick manages all the threading for logic, rendering, etc., so it's probably another Thread within Slick that's doing it - possibly somewhere in the logic thread (i.e. the stuff in the 'update() method for your game).

If you're not making any modifications in the code above, why synchronized? Have you tried it without synchronization to see if it works?

Given that Slick is supposed to handle the rendering and logic threads/loops for you, I think you might have better luck if you eased off a little bit, and let Slick do it's thing. Could be that you don't need to do synchronization here at all.